# How to pass the parameter to the config.yml object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have the config.yml which contains

```
dev:
    url: http://dev.com 
    host: dev.com
    port: 1234
stage:
    url: http:// abc.stage.xyz.com
    host: stage.com
    port: 4567
prod:
   url: http://nnn.prod.com
   host: prod.com
   port: 5698
```

In the feature file I write in scenarios as

```
scenario1: navigate to dev url
Given I navigate to the dev url

scenario2: navigate to stage_url
Given I navigate to the stage url

scenario3: navigate to prod_url
Given I navigate to the prod url
```

In the step definition

```
Then /^I navigate to the (.*) url$/ do |type|
env_config = $config.<type>.to_hash

#example
#env_config = $config.dev.to_hash
#env_config = $config.stage.to_hash

@browser.go_to(env_config['url'])
end
```

$config in evn.rb as

```
FigNewton.yml_directory = 'config'
FigNewton.load('config.yml')
$config = FigNewton
```

Question :- How I can map the type to the $config in the same format I mentioned in the example.It doesn't work like env_config = $config[type]

Comment: If `$config['dev_url']` returns `"http://dev.com"`, you can use `@browser.go_to($config[url_type])`

Comment: Actually I was using  as FigNewton.yml_directory = 'config'
FigNewton.load('config.yml')
$config = FigNewton. Also in the config.yml we have structure like dev: dev_url: dev_host: dev_port:, stage: stage_url: stage_port: etc.  so we were doing like dev_config = $config.<type>.to_hash to get everything related to dev if we pass type as dev in the step defination. The dev_config['dev_host'] , dev_config['dev_port'] etc. It doesn't work like $config[type] to pull out the values related to dev. so is there any way we can pass the type ?

Comment: Could your edit your question and add those details?

Comment: I have done that.you can have a look now.

Comment: please let  me know if any more info required.